# Python - Seperate alphanumeric list into integer and string

Tags: python, regex, list

I was trying to manipulate a csv file containing data like this:

```
['193T','4234234234'],['30T','54353456346'],['203K','4234234234'],['19E','4234234234']
```

The alphanumeric string should be separated into a number and the single character and then put back into an array as an int() and a string already. The second step would then be to cluster all of the same characters and sort them by the integer.

Ending up with something like this:

```
[19,'E',4234234234],[203,'K',4234234234],[30,'T',54353456346],[193,'T',4234234234]
```

I hope you can grasp the idea behind it.

Thank you very much for help in advance.

Comment: Is the alphabetic character always at the end of the alphanumeric string?

Comment: To me this doesn't seem like a regex question, because you are able to precisely address each token (the last character `a[-1]`, and all characters except the last `a[:-1]`). There is no need to search for a pattern.

Comment: Yes the char is always at the end so probably it boils down to th "-1" solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [['193T','4234234234'],
     ['30T','54353456346'],
     ['203K','4234234234'],
     ['19E','4234234234']]

# Using a list comprehension
[[int(i[0][:-1]), i[0][-1], int(i[1])] for i in l]
```

Output

```
[[193, 'T', 4234234234],
 [30, 'T', 54353456346],
 [203, 'K', 4234234234],
 [19, 'E', 4234234234]]
```

Then you can sort using the second element as the `key`.

```
sorted([[int(i[0][:-1]), i[0][-1], int(i[1])] for i in l], key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Output

```
[[19, 'E', 4234234234L],
 [203, 'K', 4234234234L],
 [193, 'T', 4234234234L],
 [30, 'T', 54353456346L]]
```

Comment: @Rishi I did not notice that they wanted sorted results. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is your solution creating new lists, or using references to the existing list? If the former, then performance may degrade with a large data set.

Answer (score 1):

If the alphabetic character is always at the end of the string, then you can use this:

```
>>> entries = (['193T','4234234234'],['30T','54353456346'],['203K','4234234234'],['19E','4234234234'])
>>> entries = tuple([int(entry[0][:-1]), entry[0][-1], entry[1]] for entry in entries)
>>> print entries
([193, 'T', '4234234234'], [30, 'T', '54353456346'], [203, 'K', '4234234234'], [19, 'E', '4234234234'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint

# Pretty printer (for nice output)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

# Test data
arr = [
['193T','4234234234'],['30T','54353456346'],['203K','4234234234'],['19E','4234234234']
]

for x in arr:
    # Regex search of string
    m = re.search("(?i)(\d+)([a-z])", x[0])
    if m:
        number = int(m.group(1))
        character = m.group(2)
        x.pop(0)
        x.insert(0, character)
        x.insert(0, number)

# Sort the results
result = sorted(sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(1))

pp.pprint(result)
```